# Column change order in unix csv file

Tags: csv, unix, solaris

I would like to change the column order in the below csv, on Solaris unix. As is:

```
cat mytest.csv
NAME,22015731,Fri Sep 01 05:30:21 2017,Fri Sep 01 05:45:26 2017
```

Desired:

```
cat mytest.csv
NAME,Fri Sep 01 05:30:21 2017,Fri Sep 01 05:45:26 2017,22015731
```

How is this possible to be done?

and if possible how can i do it for multiple files in a current dir?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

awk -F, '{ print $1","$3","$4","$2 }' mytest.cvs

should work. This is basic unix.
-F option allow you to select the separator character of your fields in your line.

Comment: This deletes all of the commas, and leaves output that is not comma separated.

Comment: This doesnt quite handle the newline character at the end of the last character

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$2}' FS=, OFS=, mytest.csv > tmp; mv tmp mytest.csv
```

To work on multiple files, write a loop:

```
for file in $(generate-list-of-files): do
  ...
done
```

Comment: FS is file separator; OFS is output file separator?